# Mac OS X: strikethrough the text in a label (NSTextField)

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nstextfield, strikethrough

Is it possible to strikethrough the text in a label (`NSTextField`)?

I have tried to use the Font Panel, but apparently these are ignored when I try to set them:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this, assuming `_textField` is set as an outlet in your xib:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
  NSMutableAttributedString *as = [[_textField attributedStringValue] mutableCopy];
  [as addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:(NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue range:NSMakeRange(0, [as length])];
  [_textField setAttributedStringValue:[as autorelease]];
}
```

Edit:

If you want to write a custom strikethrough `NSTextFieldCell` subclass instead, the only method that should be necessary to override is `setStringValue:`

```
- (void) setStringValue:(NSString *)aString
{
  NSMutableAttributedString *as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aString];
  [as addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:(NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue range:NSMakeRange(0, [as length])];
  [self setAttributedStringValue:[as autorelease]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that in the `awakeFromNib` I don't know the length of the text that will be inserted in the text field. In fact, I use Cocoa Bindings and _I don't ever directly control the content_ of the text field. There is no a way to strikethrough a label regardless of its content?

Comment: I understand more clearly now. `NSTextFieldCell` only has `font` and `color` attributes.  You could solve this problem with a custom `NSTextFieldCell` subclass (it shouldn't be too difficult to write), or you could bind to a custom glue object that would call `setAttributedStringValue:` on your text field whenever its setter was called via bindings.  Or you could forego bindings entirely. None of the solutions are particularly elegant, but I think they would work.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea of subclass `NSTextFieldCell`. I create a subclass called `StrikethroughTextFieldCell` and I reimplement the method `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:`: `- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView { [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView]; NSMutableAttributedString *as = [self.attributedStringValue mutableCopy]; [as addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:(NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue range:NSMakeRange(0, as.length)]; [self setAttributedStringValue:as];
}`. Unfortunately, however, does not work as expected.

Comment: You should only have to override `setStringValue:`.  I've updated my answer to show this.  Also, obviously you'll need to set the custom cell class in IB.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Unfortunately, it seems to me that the method `setStringValue:`is never called when I use Cocoa Bindings. This is why I tried, unsuccessfully, to override `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:`.

Comment: Just a short update: it seems the `setObjectValue:`is called, probably because the value of my `NSTextFieldCell` is bounded to a `NSNumber`. Anyway, when the `setAttributedStringValue` is called it enters in a recursive loop...

Answer (score 1):

For me it works great combining the approach by sbooth of creating a custom `NSTextFieldCell` and overriding `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` as posted below:

```
- (void) drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    [self setAttributedStringFromStringValue];
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}


- (void) setAttributedStringFromStringValue {  // add strikethrough
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.stringValue];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:(NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    [self setAttributedStringValue:attributedString];
}
```